# REstkit Error on Get operation

Tags: ios, rest, restkit

I'm doing a Restkit GET operation but getting an error with Restkit. I tried the same operation with the REST COnsole on Chrome and it works:

DEtails of the GET operation are:
URL: https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints
Operation: GET 
Authorization Header: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

With the Chrome REST Console, it works and I get the proper response in JSON.

With Restkit, it doesn't work. THese are my Restkit codes:

```
//trying restkit
    NSURL *endpoint = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.ez-point.com/"];
    RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:endpoint];
    [objectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];
    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"ezpoints" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
       //NSLog(mappingResult);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
        //NSLog(operation);
        //NSLog(error);
    }];
```

I'm getting this error:

```
2013-10-25 11:00:11.690 EZ-POINT[1089:c07] I restkit:RKLog.m:34 RestKit logging initialized...
2013-10-25 11:00:12.820 EZ-POINT[1089:c07] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:180 GET 'https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints'
2013-10-25 11:00:14.184 EZ-POINT[1089:4507] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:576 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/html" UserInfo=0x110a3560 {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x110b42b0>}
2013-10-25 11:00:14.185 EZ-POINT[1089:4507] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:243 GET 'https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints' (401 Unauthorized / 0 objects) [request=0.0000s mapping=0.0000s total=1.3657s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/html" UserInfo=0x110a3560 {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x110b42b0>}
2013-10-25 11:00:14.599 EZ-POINT[1089:c07] Failure
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error already gives a hint: it doesn't accept "text/xml" as a content type by default. Right now, it accepts

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- application/json

You can register it using `RKMIMETypeSerialization` and add "text/xml" to one of the accepted content types:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:RKMIMETypeTextXML];
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"text/xml"];
```

Comment: Yes, because you didn't register the serialization class (see edited answer).

Comment: With your code, I'm getting an error:  Unknown receiver 'RKXMLReaderSerialization'; did you mean RKURLEncodedSerialization?

Comment: No (https://github.com/RestKit/RKXMLReaderSerialization). But: I read your question again and it seems as if the server returns the wrong content type (text/xml) because you are actually getting JSON. So just register json serialization for this mime type or adjust your server settings (which is the preferred way).

Comment: You are right, its just right now that I noticed this, Sorry & thank you for your help !!

Comment: The server should know to return JSON or you should set the `Accept` header.

Comment: i do this but have now: "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json",
    "text/xml"
)}, got text/html"